# enable/disable NTP service on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu, daemon, ntp, ntpd

Our application runs on Ubuntu 12.04 precise. On this server, we have both `ntpdate` and `ntp`. How to enable and disable `ntp` service on-demand?

I tried

```
sudo update-rc.d -f ntp remove/default
```

and

```
sudo update-rc.d ntp enable/disable
```

, but when I reboot the server the `ntp` service starts running! I suspect `ntpdate` to start the `ntp` service on reboot. I removed the `ntpdate` package from one of my experimental server- then `ntp` didn't starts on reboot after issuing the command `update-rc.d ntp disable`.

Is there a way to control this or is there way to permanently disable `ntpdate`?

Answer (score 1):

Try `sudo update-rc.d ntp stop 0 1 2 3 4 5 6`

Reference: `man update-rc.d`